# Reason for choosing metric tensor determinant in volume measure

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

Under a co-ordinate transformation the flat space volume measure transforms as $\mathrm{d}^4 x \rightarrow |J|\mathrm{d}^4 x$, where $J$ is the Jacobian matrix. Now, in matrix notation, this co-ordinate transform transforms the covariant metric tensor as $J^{-1}J^{-1}g$, and the determinant thereof then transforms as $|J|^{-2}|g|$, which justifies considering the now invariant volume measure $|g|^{\frac{1}{2}}\mathrm{d}^4 x$. Considering however that the determinant of any second rank tensor $a_{\mu\nu}$ must transform as $|J|^{-2}|a|$, why do we select the metric tensor in particular to define the invariant measure?

Comment: The metric is a given and defines the geometry of your manifold. There are other types of volumes, like the symplectic volume. If you have a symplectic form $\omega$ on $M^{2n}$, then $\omega^n=\omega\wedge\cdots\wedge \omega$ gives a perfectly good volume measure too. It depends on what's natural to the problem.

Comment: So does that mean that any other choice of tensor also defines a perfectly good measure? Calling it the natural choice isn't theoretically satisfying.

Comment: Lots of tensors can give measures. Sometimes you want to use a different (weighted) measure. In GR you have the metric, so that is indeed the natural one in that setting.

Comment: I don't personally understand the use of the word natural unless there are clear reasons not to choose some other measures. Anyway, does that mean that using some other tensor is perfectly valid as well?

Comment: You're using your metric to measure lengths. It's natural to measure volumes with it too.

Comment: Also note that many notions commonly used in e.g. general relativity could have been chosen differently if one is not convinced by using "natural" objects. A prime example is the connection (covariant derivative). The expression (usually written down in local coordinates in physics textbooks) for the Christoffel symbols in terms of the metric is the result of a very specific, *natural* choice, namely the unique connection which is both torsion-free and metric compatible ($\nabla g=0$). Indeed, Einstein spend a good many years experimenting with field theories based on different connections.